# I quit. Here's why.

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have offered my resignation as a moderator to the SE team and I think it's important that I provide some explanation here.  Principally, I decided over the past weekend to pull the advertising for math.SE from a local professional newsletter because I was no longer comfortable recommending the site to my professional friends and colleagues, and given that state, I don't think it's appropriate for me to be a moderator.

For a little more than a month, nearly every visit to math.SE and meta.math.SE has left me feeling ill.  From the moderator's view, there is a constant stream of nasty comments on the main site and frequent attacks on us and between users on the meta site.  A small number of very loud users have a tendency to make overly-broad assertions about the moderators and draw conclusions from them (e.g. that we are not math people, that we are 20-somethings, that we don't know what USENET was like) and/or to assert that they have more experience than we do without any proof behind that assertion.  It has been similarly asserted that the experience of MathOverflow trumps the much longer and much larger experience of StackOverflow, SuperUser and ServerFault.

From my personal perspective, there is a fundamental misunderstanding that is generating a lot of the ugliness on meta.  A small number of very loud users seem to think that the goal of math.SE is to create the perfect math Q&A site and so they persist in demanding changes to the SE model, under the premise that math people are somehow different from normal people or programming people or other people.  My understanding—as in, when I saw this site proposed on area51 and first joined, before I was a moderator—is that the goal of math.SE is to create a StackExchange Q&A site for math questions.  By this, I mean that it is a fundamental part of the site that it has the same model and rules and behaviors as the other SE sites.

It has been suggested more than once that it is more important to retain users who have contributed a lot to this site than to ensure that those users behave appropriately; perhaps this should be taken as an indication that failing to ensure appropriate behavior from users will serve to drive away users who contribute a lot to this site.

I hope that once I no longer see math.SE from the perspective of a moderator, I will want to contribute again and perhaps even recommend the site to my friends and colleagues.

Comment: I am not sure whether to upvote this question or downvote it. I agree with what Isaac says (the talk about math sites being _substantially_ different from others is pure BS, IMO), but don't like the idea of having a moderator quit, when the new elections are probably so close...

Comment: Math is an outlier.  The relation between Q and A has a time-, circumstance- and poster-independent core that is much rarer on a programming (or DIY, cooking, etc) site where things are temporary and contingent on OS, job, or whatever. This implies an "eternal" accretion quality to answers, which are addressed to mankind and not only the OP.  There is a historical and archival dimension involving sources.  There is a problem-solving subculture different from, and usually nonexistent in, other subjects.  Most math seen by most humans is as schoolwork or homework.  This adds up to DIFFERENT.

Comment: @T..: Have you _actively_ participated in _any_ non-mathematical stackexchange site to claim DIFFERENCE?

Comment: @Moron: if you know of open-use non-mathematical sites (SE or other) with a quantitatively and qualitatively similar combination of peculiarities, which ones are they?  Certainly *some* math traits listed above, and others I could not fit into a 500 character comment, are manifested *sometimes* on other types of site, but the combination and prominence of all those features is unique to math and (maybe) a few other mathematical ones like physics.

Comment: @T..: Regarding your differences. 1) Eternal: Even programming questions are eternal, and the whole premise of stackoverflow is based on having questions/answers being eternal. In any case, how is that relevant to having a different kind of site? 2) Source: Totally unimportant. You don't need any site support to cite sources etc. 3) Problem Solving subculture. Too vague to even discuss. Are these differences enough to warrant substantial changes in the stackexchange platform? I don't think so. Sorry, I still think the claims that math somehow needs to be different from other SE sites is BS.

Comment: Whether the platform "needs" to be different is a separate, or perhaps consequent, matter.  What is clear is that math *is* different.  re:(1) Programming questions are usually contingent on particular systems-of-the-moment.  Nobody will be reading solutions to COBOL queries for very long, especially if they were for your job, but sci.math newsgroup messages from the 1980's are still being cited. (2) You are not prevented from discussing sources, but site support would *help* as it is *logically independent* of the Q&A. (3) Problem-solving needs its own site, to its own and math.SE's benefit.

Comment: @T..: Of course math is different. That is why we have a different site in the first place. Also, how does the current site not address eternality? It was actually built on the premise of Q&A being eternally useful! Perhaps the current platform is not ideal, but I don't see any major issues with it either (apart from perhaps better full text search in the latex code). The recent CAPTCHA discussion about math being different was BS too, IMO. If math requires so much thinking, why don't you do it before posting? (I do agree CAPTCHA for frequent edits of the same answer is kind of pointless).

Comment: @Moron: there are enough examples for a separate thread. The "answered" status of questions is in tension with the eternal-accretion model, as is the lack of separation between poster-dependent metadata and the mathematics of the question. (Splitting that data from question content would improve ANY q&a site, IMO).  Including "is it homework" in a personal metadata questionnaire would kill off a bit of recurring nastiness on the site, and having a Sources field would improve things on the historical/archival, accretion, and homework/plagiarism fronts (so again would reduce the ugliness).

Comment: re: the lovely comment "if math requires so much thinking, why don't you do it before posting" -- you are confusing me with the author of the CAPTCHA discussion.  All I have had to say about CAPTCHA is that it doesn't personally bother me but the bot-detection algorithm could be greatly improved.  I do agree, however, with Bill Dubuque's opinion in the CAPTCHA thread that math having more internal structure and connections has implications for a math discussion site, such as postings being revised and updated more often.

Comment: @T..: The issue about "answered"/"homework" etc exists in _most_ other SE sites. The will always be multiple ways to skin a cat. There will always be users trying to get their homework done on the internet and people will be divided on how to treat those. Whether it be math or programming or physics.  Btw, the meaning of a "ticked" answer is that that was the one that helped the OP most. It is not necessarily the best. It does not even have to be correct! The community based voting is supposed to decide what the community thinks is the best answer, irrespective of OP's opinion.

Comment: @T..: I agree the CAPTCHA can probably be made better, especially for multiple edits of the same answer. I only brought that up, because I thought you might indirectly be referring to it. In any case this is an issue with programming too. Posting a well written correctly working program usually requires multiple updates! Probably more so, than the average math answer here. The issue has more to do with the posting habits of the user and less with the kind of site it is. I don't really see the need for such frequent edits, whatever content you might be posting.

Comment: And my apologies to Isaac about the multiple pings.

Comment: OK, but the detailed merits of (or need for) particular site upgrades are a matter for another thread.  I am addressing only the "it is BS" comment above.  Given the limitations of the comments I think more than enough indicators have been provided of a substantial and operationally relevant difference between math and non-math Q&A forums.  It does not mean that a generic Q&A platform is unusable, but it does have subtle and not-so-subtle implications for how well the platform "fits" and even how many arguments develop on the site and the meta.

Comment: @T..: If you would care to compile your arguments as a separate thread, I would like to see them. If I was one of the SE developers, the arguments would really need to be compelling enough to consider spending development time on it. Frankly, all the meta threads and discussions I have seen, haven't provided any compelling arguments (I might have missed some, I don't spend all my time in meta ;-)) to make substantial changes to the generic Q&A platform. Anyway...

Comment: @Isaac: "I hope that...I will want to contribute again..."  Me too.  You are a valuable contributor to the site.  Thank you for your service.

Comment: Am I to assume from the direction all these talks seem to be going that adapting SE 2.0 to mathematics (or backwards, I don't know) was a Procrustean fit? On another note, all the issues are valid, but something about the tone of these meta talks seems off-putting. I don't know why. @Isaac: you were a great mod, IMHO, and it is rather depressing that you have to step down, though I understand perfectly that having to deal with so many noisy users is detrimental to mental health. (I was under the assumption that this site would actually need much less moderation than most, but well...)

Comment: @J.M.: any first attempt is Procrustean to some extent.  The difficulty here is that success of the platform in another domain has created the conviction that "the same will work everywhere" (e.g., as a platform for meta, for math.SE, for the combination of the two) and a consequent resistance to modifications of the model. Another poster here described it as a case of having a hammer and thinking everything is a nail.  This type of thinking is unfalsifiable because active site use looks like a success.  However, the "deep problems" Jeff mentions suggest that some lack of fit does exist.

Comment: @T..: I'm not even so sure that it's a lack of fit.  I think that it's a matter of the conviction you mentioned being the prevailing view among the active moderators.  The SE software is fine.  The problem is people trying to force SO culture down our throats.  We're a separate community with our own quirks.

Comment: @Moron: Do you really think it is "BS" to claim that the subject matter of mathematics is radically different from other subjects?

Comment: @Bill: The way I parsed @Moron's comment was that it was BS to use "math is different" and "math needs so much thinking" in relation to the CAPTCHA discussion (in short, why not post only after you have a sure-fire *magnum opus* to share, so that you don't bump into the bot-detector so much?) On my part, unstable browsers have taught me to write answers out first in a plaintext editor, paste the mess into the answer box, and make cosmetic changes as needed based on the preview.

Comment: @J.M. Because I edit many related posts at once - see my second question on Captcha. It's most certainly not "BS" - the rich web of interconnections is an innate part of mathematics. One shouldn't be penalized for attempting to build that web here.

Comment: @Bill: mathematics is even different from other math subjects (for purposes of a Q&A site). CS-theory is entirely mathematical but there is nothing like the problem-solving/competition subculture, the posting of elementary problems all the way down to basic arithmetic, or the share of the general population exposed to it. Physics and statistics also have their differences from math, most notably the smaller population of aficionados. These are less "radical" differences than comparing math to cooking or pest control, but they all have implications that in Q&A terms make math an outlier.

Comment: @Bill: I agree with the interconnections thing, so I didn't really agree with the "BS" (which is a bit harsh, IMHO); just saying how I read the statement. I still consider it a bit arse-backwards that high-rep users still need to undergo CAPTCHA interrogations (and if there indeed has ever been a compromise of a high-rep account, shouldn't there be an option for nuking?)

Comment: @T..: In any other field one person could master it all. That hasn't been true in math for over a century. That shows how much more breadth and depth math has. It's difficult for non-mathematicians to truly appreciate the magnitude of this contrast. The math web is *far* richer- many orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Isaac; I apologize for all this pinging I contributed to; this is really one of the problems with using SE 2.0 for meta stuff I think.

Comment: @Bill: At this point, I would heartily disagree with "in any other field one person can master it all"; this is not the province of mathematics alone. I would say every field is crawling with specialists.

Comment: @J.M. Really? What field?

Comment: @J.M.: unfortunately the "pure BS" references started in the very first comment, prior to any discussion of CAPTCHA, so there is less chance of vindicating that remark by equating its scope with that of the later "BS" claims.   Even within 500-char limits on the number of counterexamples, it is clear that there are many differences between math and all other subjects, and those differences impinge upon the site.  (It is only a difference, by the way, not a higher ranking or special status.)

Comment: @Bill: Dear Bill, Is it really true that one person can master all of physics?  I've heard people say this of Feynman, but am not knowledgeable enough to judge whether it is really true.  And even it were true of him (who was in any case clearly an extreme outlier), is it true, or even possible, now?

Comment: @Bill: To use chemistry (my home field, as it were) as an example, not everything a physical chemist looks at would be of interest to a synthetic chemist. (Biology is even much more split-up than chemistry, and I'm too lazy to list examples) To use the apparently looked-down upon cooking as another example, there's not much overlap between different cuisines. My point is that it is unfair to say that only mathematics can there be no "master of all", the world nowadays is so complicated and we are people who only have so much space in the noggin.

Comment: @T: I never read any of these as "mathematics >>> everything else", FWIW. :) But apparently no one wishes to budge, hence my "Procrustean" comment.

Comment: @Bill: I never claimed that mathematics is not different from other subjects. I claimed that justifying the need for a radically different platform based on the subject being different is BS and the comments so far don't seem to have helped in changing my mind. I really haven't seen any reasonable arguments which prove that the current SE2.0 platform is unsuitable for mathematics. All I see are some lofty descriptions of mathematics.

Comment: @Moron: I don't recall anyone demanding "radically different platform" or declaring SE2 "unsuitable for mathematics".  Do you?  I do think that the Area 51 process (difficulty of getting sites for math subfields started) combined with the lack of crossposting can certainly cross the threshold of unsuitability as the user base of math.SE grows from thousands to hundreds of thousands.  Based on StackOverflow and sci.math numbers the potential user base for math.SE without splitting off subgroups, could easily be close to a million or more. Current model would collapse before getting there.

Comment: @T..: Maybe the words I used were a bit strong, I give you that.

Comment: @Matt: To clarify my remark: I think that a very talented student could master all of physics (as it is today) in one lifetime. However, that would be highly impossible for mathematics.

Comment: @J.M. The point of my remarks is merely to attempt to emphasize that math is a much more richly connected web of ideas than most other fields. Expressing those  connections here places greater demands on the software platform. Most SE forums don't have users who actively edit (very) old posts - adding links to generalizations, specializations, polishing proofs, etc. But such self-organization is essential for an evolving body of mathematics.

Comment: I understand what you were getting at, @Bill, but I believe you could have pleaded this position without making an extreme statement. As for your answer to @Matt, if I am to believe what my friends have told me, mastering **all** of current physics is untenable.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think the statement is extreme in any way. IMO it would take many, many more lifetimes to master all of current mathematics than it would any other field. But let's drop that since it's far too tangential to the matter at hand.

Comment: @Bill: I suppose we will have to agree to disagree, then. Our perceptions of magnitude fundamentally differ, it looks.

Comment: FWIW, I think that there are certain advantages in non-professional mathematicians being moderators, as long as they are not heavy-handed.

Comment: @George S, the argument is the same for having experts and non-experts: represent all sectors of the user population.  However, what is more important, as your "not heavy-handed" criterion suggests, is to reduce as much as possible the dependence on moderators.  All else being equal, it is better to have expert moderators than non-experts, but little-or-no moderation would be better than a slate of moderators with ideal mix of backgrounds. It would help everyone to have better tools to give users control, instead of better control of the users, or better users in control.

Comment: @T..: This notion of "little-or-no moderation" is exactly what I had in mind. If the moderators are not professional mathematicians themselves, they would leave the users alone to a large extent for the stuff on the main site. I simply love how unobtrusive the moderators on this site are! I was never harassed even a single time here at the math.SE site. I in fact have some fear that such peace and freedom would be lost if more "active" moderators gain the throne in the next election.

Answer (score 40):

I'm sorry you have had such a negative recent moderating experience.  In the best of circumstances, moderation is a rather thankless job.  So I want to take this opportunity to thank you for your service.

There is an undeniable tension between the SE model and the goal to have a math Q&A site which serves the interests of the existing math Q&A community.  I don't myself know how this will play out in the end: maybe there is room for compromise and collaboration, but maybe there isn't.  We'll see.

I do want to acknowledge that a (very) small number of users have been absolutely vicious in their treatment of the moderators of this site.  I was horrified when I first saw this, but like the frog in the pot I guess I got somewhat used to it as time passed.  I'm sorry about that.  Once again: good job, thank you.

Comment: "Like the frog in the pot I guess I got somewhat used to it as time passed" This is **extremely** disturbing to read, and this is what I was trying to tell you in comments of the linked question. It is absolutely imperative that we *bring back civility*.

Comment: @Jeff: it can be brought back by example, not by force.

Comment: @T.. ironically that suspension that Pete was so disturbed by, is actually the solution to the problem he is describing. That's why I brought it up in the first place. Pete, maybe you should be elected a moderator; you seem like a good candidate?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: and I was trying to tell you that many of your own messages are being viewed as uncivil.  (As a minor example, your response to this question conveys an opinion of the users of this site as simply a bunch of troublemakers.)  I asked you whether you felt that you were more qualified than everyone else to judge what was civil behavior, and your answer was "yes".  This is not a perspective conducive to building a healthy community.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not referring to any specific instance, but the general philosophy of heavy-handed "civility or else".  Unless you and Isaac are reading an entirely different set of discussions than I have seen, a lot of the supposed incivility was just openness of opinion without any negative personal content.  As Pete mentions, if anything your own messages were the more personalized, but I don't begrudge that to you (apart from the fact that it's your site) and would rather have a community with (1) more freedom of discussion, (2) less of the relentless flag-waving use of the word "community".

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: okay, this time at least you are misunderstanding me.  I never said that I was against suspension of users in all cases.  That is far from the case, and longtime MO users know that I have spoken out against truly problematic behavior.  Absolutely suspensions are appropriate in some cases, and as I said, I am surprised that one particular user was not suspended sooner/more often.  My point was that suspensions should not be discussed when people are calmly and politely discussing site issues.  The meta site needs to be *a priori* receptive to that, or its existence is pointless.

Comment: @pete I'm a policeman; are policemen qualified to police? Do you ask this question of every cop you meet -- "what makes you qualified to be a policeman"? That's also not a perspective conducive to building a healthy relationship between yourself and the forces mandated to provide law and order in the community. Regardless, you should participate in the election if you want to become a moderator, then I'll ask you whether you feel more qualified than everyone else to be one. :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: you are obviously not a policeman but a website administrator.  And my point was not to question whether you are qualified but rather whether you are so qualified so as to make it wise to act unilaterally and in the face of significant reasoned opposition.  It doesn't seem like you are listening carefully to what I'm saying or are interested in a serious discussion.  That's unfortunate.

Comment: @Pete it's disappointing that you would refer to the co-founder of the organization -- someone who cares deeply about the success of these communities -- as a "website administrator". I'm here because there are deep problems within this community. Exhibit A: this very question. So you can either fight me, insult me (as you just did) or you can work with me as a possible elected moderator to make this site more civil. Which will it be?

Comment: @Jeff: while it is theoretically possible that "deep problems within this community" arise from odious users and bad site culture, I again suggest the possibility that there are fundamental *impersonal* causes (structural, technological, demographic) specific to a math site that will keep arising even if the entire current math.SE user population leaves and is replaced. Years of running a blog community may not be such relevant experience for running a non-blog in an area of one's non-expertise.  Input of subject experts (e.g., mathematicians) may be more useful and worth heeding.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I didn't realize that "website administrator" was an insult.  I honestly thought that you were, among other things, the head administrator of this website.  (I am also under the impression that you are not in fact a police officer, but I don't know anything about your private life.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.)  I'm sorry that I offended you, although I don't quite understand why what I said caused offense.  Please feel free to contact me privately to explain.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Policemen are ultimately appointed by the people. You deserve all our thanks for creating the SE platform, but that itself does not make you a leader of the community. Just because you own the toys doesn't mean that you can dictate the rules of the game. I think that a democratic election of moderators from among the active contributors to the site is the only solution. And even then the less the moderators have to do, the better.

Comment: @jyot I don't recall voting any of our local police staff into office. In the general sense, my taxes pay their salaries, just like your time spent here pays mine. And policemen are given the trust to do some very uncivil things, like arrest people, in the name of the greater civic good. I help govern this site -- just like every other site under our banner -- when there are extreme problems: just scroll up and re-read this question to see why I am here.

Comment: @Jeff: Just because what you're saying is true (that you're here to clean up because there's actual problems and that might require knocking a few heads) doesn't mean that it's helpful to say it that way.  You're causing problems by behaving like a stereotypical policeman who cares more about asserting their authority than keeping the peace.  If you need to come in here and ban someone that's great. But I think it'd be helpful for you to step away for a little while to calm down and then try not to say things that make the situation worse rather than better.

Comment: @noah in my opinion, civility was not enforced, which led directly to "I do want to acknowledge that a (very) small number of users have been absolutely vicious in their treatment of the moderators of this site. I was horrified when I first saw this, but like the frog in the pot I guess I got somewhat used to it as time passed." This is the single most disturbing sentence I have ever read on *any* of our sites. From this point on, **civility will be enforced** -- for all users. Anyone who is not comfortable with that needs to find other places on the internet to spend their time.

Comment: @Noah: this the first time I have seen SE personnel engage in two-way discussion of general site management. I think they should be encouraged to continue, not leave.  The policeman metaphor is badly flawed but debating its merits comes at the expense of discussing site issues with those in a position to make many changes.

Comment: @T..: Fair enough.  I don't want Jeff to go away, I just think things might be more productive if he slept on things.

Comment: @noah unfortunately I've been "sleeping on" math.se for weeks now. It isn't magically getting any better by itself. I am pushing hard for moderator elections next week though, so if you don't want me here then **MAKE ME OBSOLETE**. Get elected, take control of your own community, and stop the rampant frog-boiling incivility.

Comment: Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Comment: @RobinChapman ostensibly the public. When the public no longer can do so, then Nero will play his fiddle while the city burns. (note I'm going as poetic as you are)

Comment: @pete I didn't realize that formal acceptance of the apology was necessary -- so to make this formal and proper, I accept your apology w/r/t "website administrator".

Answer (score 21):

Like everyone else I'd like to thank you for the time spent moderating.  I feel particularly thankful because I've always felt a little bit guilty that I was too busy to be a moderator myself.

I occasionally visit both math.SE and meta.math.SE and I wanted to say that although every time I stop by the latter it seems like a mess, every time I look at the former it seems to me that it's working very well.

What I mean to say is that although as a moderator you have to wade through the muck that does occur, I think it may be helpful for you to realize that from the point of view of an occasional visitor the site you've been working on really does look good.  Your time hasn't been wasted even though it might feel that way to you right now.

Answer (score 12):

Isaac,

Thanks for being a moderator. I concur that there's something unique about the math community as it exists here. Certainly the number of mod flags and problem "needs moderator intervention" issues here is about two orders of magnitude higher than any other community under our banner.

We're talking about this now and we are going to try the following:

1. Democratic moderator elections using our new site code to do so (should be available by the end of next week)
2. We will cross-reference with Math Overflow, where possible, to coordinate bans. If a user has been banned from Math Overflow, except in the case of extraordinary extenuating circumstances, they will be banned from here as well.

Comment: More positive and less tendentious examples of how math is different (for purposes of a Q & A site) were posted in the comments under the question/resignation.  Without a 500-character limit the list would be much longer.  It has implications for the "fit" to the SE software platform.

Comment: @Jeff: I find it extremely hard to believe that mod issues here are *two* orders of magnitude higher than any other community. Do you have statistics to back this up this claim?

Comment: @Jeff: MO actually has a very light hand with actually banning people, so I doubt that's really going to help much.  (I've actually argued on meta.MO that something like SO's exponential approach would be better there, but Anton prefers a more patient approach.)

Comment: Dear Jeff, Does "problem ... issues here" in your answer mean on the main site or on Meta?   Thanks in advance for your answer, and best wishes,

Comment: In connection with Matt E's question and Isaac's statement about frequent and ongoing nastiness on the main site, it would be informative to know how much hostile material (numbers of hostile comments or answers) is deleted by moderators on the math.SE main site.  Are we talking about a few per day? Hundreds per week?  Other than interrogation and accusation of actual or suspected homework posters, I am not seeing much negative material.  10K (2K) tools did not show many closures or flags during the beta.  Is there a [flamewar] tag I should be searching for?

Comment: @bill http://tex.stackexchange.com has similar levels of traffic and a similarly technical bent. Critical mod messages between meta/parent: 14. This site has *156*. So, I may have exaggerated a bit: it's only one order of magnitude. But, math.se also has the dubious distinction of being the *only* site in the network where one pro-tem moderator quit, one permanent user ban has been applied, and two users requested permanent site deletion. The data tells the story, and it's not good.

Comment: Comparing the "technical bent" of a TeX site and a general math site is *exactly* the kind of inattention to demographics that would cause growth problems.  A TeX group is by its nature limited to people with a need (or hobby) for technical typesetting. This is a selected group -- older, more educated, etc -- compared to the diverse user base of an all-levels math group where non-technical users are posting problems from their math classes.  TeX is impersonal and less prone to contests of interpretation, ego, or "handwaving".  *Of course* you expect much less antagonism on a TeX site.

Comment: @T.. these stats are also true for other peer sites in the network of similar vintage. And as I mentioned, math is the only site *in the entire network* where one pro-tem moderator quit, one permanent user ban has been applied, and two users requested permanent site deletion. On all our other SE 2.0 sites *combined* we've had exactly one user deletion to date ... and certainly no permanent user bans or pro-tem moderators quitting out of frustration.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't know what you consider peer sites, and your sample size is five hard-to-generalize events.  Due to reasons of content and demographics a math site will have more back and forth than many others, and any structural problems (e.g., not adapting the platform to problems and phenomena that are naturally more intensive or frequent on a math site) will exacerbate the tension.  If there is an excess of problems on the math site after proper accounting for other factors, it is likely structural rather than due to a lack of policemen.

Comment: Also, can you clarify how the numbers compare for problems considering the main, non-meta, sites only, and also what the incidence rate is over time?  Was that 156 main-plus-meta "critical mod messages" (what does that expression mean) for math.SE in approximately three months?

Comment: @Jeff: Every math forum at this level has similar troubles. That's the nature of the beast. Because math at this level has such universal applications it attracts a much more diverse group of members than most other sites - perfect breeding ground for every sort of clash under the universe (egotistical, philosophical, pedagogical, foundational, etc). Anyone active in the older math forums knows this all too well. This might be an unpleasant surprise to younger or less experienced mods, but it would hardly ruffle the feathers of thick-skinned old-timers

Comment: @Bill, some of the closed subscription, research-oriented math mailing lists for academics have more flamewars than this site (I am thinking of FOM but I remember some lesser problems on other lists as well).  That is in an area more "prone to contests of interpretation, ego or handwaving", so maybe the same gradations apply within math as well.

Answer (score 1):

dear Isaac,

a few comments.

First of all, to the extent that moderation here took up your time, thanks for volunteering.

Second, the work done by moderators (the part requiring more than edit powers) is somewhat invisible and if it is crucial to the site that should be made clear. I  have raised, and am not the only one interested in, the question of what functions the moderation performs, which of those are beneficial, and how much can be automated or obviated by changes to the software.  Especially in light of the imminent moderator elections, any concrete information you can provide such as what number of hours per week the moderation took up for you and how they were typically spent, would be illuminating and appreciated.  Perhaps it could be done in a separate thread or an update of the old one.

Third, your discussion of a "misunderstanding" of math.SE's nature is at odds with the assertions of the site founders that SE is "like USENET 2.0".  In addition to learning the lessons from past forums that failed, this site is specifically being compared with USENET because 2.0 has not reached the functionality of 1.0, not to mention its level of freedom and laissez faire intellectual content sharing.  For as long as the site creators (and their promotional material) proudly cite USENET as a precursor and analogue of the current enterprise, the two will be compared. Comparisons will also be made with other less structurally similar math sites, but the newsgroups are for many reasons the primary point of comparison, and the SE founders did not cite them by accident.  The demographic and volume issues faced by USENET groups are just beginning to be felt on this site, but they are the same.  MathOverflow and math.SE are directly analogous to sci.math.research and sci.math, respectively, and I don't know anyone familiar with all of those forums who does not see it that way.

Fourth, I also doubt that people conversing on the meta misunderstand that, having created StackOverflow, the founders intend to clone its platform for the new sites, and have an incentive to assembly-line the expansion process without too many single-site customizations.  The actual point that some may have missed in the back-and-forth about the present and future structure of math.SE is that the role of the users here need not be a passive one.  Of course the users can make of the site what they will as content contributors, but they also have an interest in advising SE on molding the software to the needs and interests of a math site.  As Jeff Atwood has stated in his recent comments, this can be a win-win because the math site drives technology later found to be useful on the other sites, such as TeX display, and I believe that all the seemingly "special" suggestions based on needs of a math site would ultimately benefit all the SE sites, including StackOverflow and the SE 2.0 platform.

Finally, you use "e.g." as though it were heading a generic list of misguided statements here in the meta.math.SE, but in fact you criticize a single posting by a single user. It is easy enough to find the original and notice that any substantive resemblance between your summary and what was posted is relatively slight.  For instance, it was not asserted that all moderators are 20-something (though most are), or that USENET experience or an academic research background are prerequisites for moderators of the site.  It would certainly be helpful if the latter categories were well-represented among the moderators, and of course, I would prefer a setup that limits the dependence on any moderators of any background.

Whatever you may think of the above: thanks again for your time.